# Ввод в консоль 1e не воспринимается как '1' типа double и 'e' типа char

Tags: c++

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему консоль принимает ввод 1r, 1u, 1b, 1g, но при вводе 1e (речь идет именно о слитном написании), весь while пролетает и программа завершается? Связано ли это с тем, что консоль воспринимает 1e как экспоненциальную запись (а не как переменную типа double '1' и переменную типа char 'e'). Впервые здесь пишу, так что не судите строго за постановку вопроса. Вот код:

```
`#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

// This program converts UAH, RUB, BYN, EUR and GBP to USD.
// u = UAH; r = RUB; b = BYN; e = EUR; g = GBP.
// UAH == 26.34; RUB = 64.51; BYN == 2.08; EUR == 0.89; GBP == 0.79.
// Exchange rates for 28.05.2019.  

int main() {

    constexpr double uah_per_usd = 26.34;
    constexpr double rub_per_usd = 64.51;
    constexpr double byn_per_usd = 2.08;
    constexpr double eur_per_usd = 0.89;
    constexpr double gbp_per_usd = 0.79;

    double amount = 0;
    char cur = '0';

    cout << "Enter the amount of currency: " << flush;
    while (cin >> amount >> cur) {

        switch (cur) {
        case 'u':
            cout << amount << " UAH = " << amount / uah_per_usd << " USD\n";
            break;
        case 'r':
            cout << amount << " RUB = " << amount / rub_per_usd << " USD\n";
            break;
        case 'b':
            cout << amount << " BYN = " << amount / byn_per_usd << " USD\n";
            break;
        case 'e':
            cout << amount << " EUR = " << amount / eur_per_usd << " USD\n";
            break;
        case 'g':
            cout << amount << " GBP = " << amount / gbp_per_usd << " USD\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Unfortunately, no data for that currency.\n";
            break;

        }

        cout << endl << "Enter the NEW amount of currency: " << flush;
    }

    return 0;

}`
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно понимаете. Введите `1e0e` и убедитесь, что все будет в порядке...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1e` воспринимается как некорректная форма записи числа с плавающей точкой, так как отсутствует значение экспоненты (`1e-1` например), соответственно при чтении `amount` происходит ошибка и выставляется флаг `failbit`. Наверное вам имеет смысл требовать формата с пробелом `1 e` или сначала читать строку и извлекать из нее название валюты.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.